# send content type image/TIFF to the browser is not working

Tags: php, imagick

I'm using Imagick (6.7.7-4 and module version 3.2.0RC).

I am trying to create an image and render it in the browser dynamically, for example, by HTML

```
<img src='image_generator.php?QUERY_PARAMS_TO_DETERMINE_TEXT'>
```

This is the image_generator.php content:

```
/* Create text */
$draw->setFillColor('white');
$draw->setFontSize( 19 );
$draw->setGravity(Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER);
$draw->annotation(0, -50, 'points');
$image->drawImage($draw);

/* Give image a format */
$image->setImageFormat('tiff'); // png works

/* Output the image with headers */
header('Content-type: image/tiff'); // png works
echo $image;
```

When I open image_generator.php in php and the image format is set to TIFF, it automatically downloads a PHP file and does not show an image as of the PNG case.

Comment: You have either misconfigured your server, or you have missed off the opening <?php in the file.

Comment: seriously? this is part of the code.

Comment: Seriously. The error you are seeing is one of those two things, so you need to check the basic things.

Answer (score 0):

If changing the extension of the downloaded file to ".tif" results in the correct image, then, the problem is, the browser is using the page name as the file name. That's not uncommon when a server side script or applet is programmatically serving an image (or other file for download).

Change the "attachment" name using the following header.

```
/* Give image a format */
$image->setImageFormat('tiff'); // png works

/* Output the image with headers */
// This line will change the download name

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="[NAME.TIFF]");
// This line will set the Mime Type
header('Content-type: image/tiff'); 
echo $image;
```

That's it.

*I know I am years late to this party, but, because various people run into this and think it's bad code or configuration, or simply need to know how to rename their downloads, I figured I would answer it for others who run into it.*